# Why is BITS service using 8-10% of my CPU?

Tags: windows, windows-10

WMI service provider was using 8-10% so I was disabling services to see if they were the ones doing it and when I disabled BITS it went down to 0. WMI service provider usage had been up before and i disabled the service but now its BITS.

Comment: BITS is associated with Windows Update.  Windows was probably attempting to install an update.  Have you confirmed that to be the case?  *FYI: BITS will just be enabled automatically*

Comment: I try to update and it gives me an error saying "A current driver on your PC may be better than the driver we're trying to install. We'll keep trying to install."

Comment: Your going to have to provide more information, obviously Windows Update is attempting to install a device driver, but you already have a driver for the device in question.  However, device drivers are typically optional, and only installed if specifically requested.  However, Windows Update struggling to install an update, would explain the cpu usage. Have you tried to perform a reboot?

Comment: Yes i've rebooted multiple times.